# Insertion of array to file error

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I use the following code to insert array of structure to file but it crash:

```
void SaveInFile(List * pl)
{

        int i;
        int s = ListSize(pl);

        file = fopen("myFile.txt", "w");        //3shan aktb 3la file mn gded 
        for (i = 0; i <= s; i++) {
                file = fopen("myFile.txt", "a");
                fprintf(file, "IDOfprocess%s/n", pl->entry[i].ID);
                fprintf(file, "IDOfprocess%s/n", pl->entry[i].BurstTime);
        }
        fclose(file);
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If `ListSize` returns the size N for list with N elements, then: `for( i=0;i<=s;i++)` → `for( i=0;i<s;i++)`, otherwise you'll be getting *segmentation fault*.

Comment: You're calling `fopen()` inside the loop (i.e., for each entry).  Remove the second `fopen()`.  Also, what data types are `ID` and `BurstTime`?  You are using %s which implies null-terminated string, so hopefully they are indeed strings.

Comment: 1) fopen the file first in "a" mode, unless you want to "truncate" it, but anyway you can't open it s+1 time times, thus 2) remove fopen from inside the lloop

Comment: ouch... I bet you any money this will leak memory... calling `fopen` `s` times without `fclose`... don't do that oh, and check the `FILE *` returned by `fopen`, too. If it's `NULL`, something went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file multiple times without closing it.
This will do:

```
void SaveInFile(List* pl)
{

int i;
int s=ListSize(pl);

file=fopen("myFile.txt","w");//3shan aktb 3la file mn gded 
fclose(file);
for( i=0;i<=s;i++){

file=fopen("myFile.txt","a");
fprintf(file,"IDOfprocess%s/n",pl->entry[i].ID);
fprintf(file,"IDOfprocess%s/n",pl->entry[i].BurstTime);

fclose(file);
}
}
```

If you do not close the file, the content of any unwritten output buffer is not written to the file.

But what you should actually do is open the file one time and perform the append operations:

```
void SaveInFile(List* pl)
{

int i;
int s=ListSize(pl);

file=fopen("myFile.txt","w");//3shan aktb 3la file mn gded 
fclose(file);

file=fopen("myFile.txt","a");
for( i=0;i<=s;i++){

fprintf(file,"IDOfprocess%s/n",pl->entry[i].ID);
fprintf(file,"IDOfprocess%s/n",pl->entry[i].BurstTime);
}
fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: You still need to close the first fopen or you have a resource leak... may be just comment it.

Comment: how to write new line as \n print the same charachter not new line

Answer (score 1):

your `for` loop is reaching `s` and you are starting from `0` (so you are treating `s+1` elements and not `s` elements)

So it should be

```
for( i=0;i<s;i++){
```